# Interactive server-driven Flask SQL table with option to download filtered data in .csv

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, datatables

I am trying to download a SQLite queried table as .csv using `Flask`, `SQLAlchemy` (not `Flask-SQLAlchemy`) and `DataTables` (plug-in for jQuery) with the server-side processing option.

Basically, I have a query that connects to a SQLite dataset, imports the data and returns it to a DataTable.

A summary of what is already working:

- Drop down (HTML select element) to chose which table should be displayed.
- Retrieval of data given the selected table, using DataTable's "server-side processing" option, which allows the fetch of large data across multiple partial requests via Ajax request (using `offset` and `limit`).
- Filter of case insensitive text in each column, which is passed from the DataTable table to the Flask code (server-side) and retrieved accordingly. User needs to press "Enter" after typing the code to apply the text filter.
- Download of the complete displayed table as .csv.

It looks like this:
[image]

The problem that I am facing is that once I type in a filter from any column, the downloaded .csv still contains the full table instead of the filtered one. For example, when I search for "2" in `Column A` and press Enter, I see the filtered data as expected:

[image]

But when I press to download the table, the full table data is downloaded instead of the filtered one. I would like to download only the filtered data. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Below I provide a full working code with a sample SQLite "test.db" dataset with 2 tables ("table_a" and "table_b") to reproduce the code. I am using the latest versions of the packages (`Flask==3.0.0`, `pandas==2.1.3` and `SQLAlchemy==2.0.22`).

/templates/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flask Application</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css"/>

        <style>
            .text-wrap{
                white-space:normal;
            }
            .width-200{
                width:200px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Table Viewer</h1>

        <form id="selector" action="{{ url_for('.database_download') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            Select table:
            <select id="table-selector" name="table-selector">
                <!-- <option disabled selected value>Select a Dataset</option> -->
                <option value="table_a" selected>Table A</option>
                <option value="table_b">Table B</option>
            </select>

        </form>

        <br>

        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="order-columns" value="True" checked> Order columns by date</p>


        <p><input type="button" id="button-database-selector" value="Select Table" /></p>


        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div id="content-a" class="table table-striped table-hover" style="display:none; width:100%; table-layout:fixed; overflow-x:auto;">

            <table id="table-a">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>

        </div>


        <div id="content-b" class="table table-striped table-hover" style="display:none; width:100%; table-layout:fixed; overflow-x:auto;">

            <table id="table-b">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>


        </div>

        <div id="download" style="display:none">

            <p>Download table: <input type="submit" value="Download" form="selector"></button></p>

    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready( function() {

            $('input[id="button-database-selector"]').click( function() {


                if ($('input[id="order-columns"]').prop('checked')) {
                    var order_columns = 'True';
                } else {
                    var order_columns = '';
                }

                var database_selected = $('select[id="table-selector"]').val();

                // Display download button
                $('div[id="download"]').css('display', 'block');

                if (database_selected == 'table_a') {

                    // Hide all tables
                    $('div[id^="content-"]').hide();

                    // Display table
                    $('div[id="content-a"]').css('display', 'block');

                    // Setup - add a text input to each header cell
                    $('#table-a thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function () {
                        var title = $('#table-a thead tr:eq(0) th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
                        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
                    } );

                    var table = $('table[id="table-a"]').DataTable({
                        'pageLength': 50,
                        'ordering': false,
                        // 'scrollX': true,
                        // 'sScrollX': '100%',
                        'searching': true,
                        'dom': 'lrtip',
                        'orderCellsTop': true,
                        'serverSide': true,
                        'bDestroy': true,
                        'ajax': {
                            'url': "{{ url_for('.table_a') }}",
                            'type': 'GET',
                            'data': {
                                'orderColumns': order_columns,
                            },
                        },
                        'columns': [
                            { 'title': 'Column Date', 'data': 'column_date' },
                            { 'title': 'Column A', 'data': 'column_a' },
                        ],
                        'columnDefs': [
                            {
                                'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
                                    return "<div class='text-wrap width-200'>" + data + "</div>";
                                },
                                'targets': '_all',
                            }
                        ],
                    });

                    // Apply the search
                    table.columns().every( function (index) {
                        $('#table-a thead tr:eq(1) th:eq(' + index + ') input').on('keydown', function (event) {
                            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                                table.column($(this).parent().index() + ':visible')
                                    .search(this.value)
                                    .draw();
                            }
                        });
                    });

                } else if (database_selected === 'table_b') {

                    // Hide all tables
                    $('div[id^="content-"]').hide();

                    // Display table
                    $('div[id="content-b"]').css('display', 'block');

                    // Setup - add a text input to each header cell
                    $('#table-b thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function () {
                        var title = $('#table-b thead tr:eq(0) th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
                        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
                    } );

                    var table = $('table[id="table-b"]').DataTable({
                        'pageLength': 50,
                        'ordering': false,
                        // 'scrollX': true,
                        // 'sScrollX': '100%',
                        'searching': true,
                        'dom': 'lrtip',
                        'orderCellsTop': true,
                        'serverSide': true,
                        'bDestroy': true,
                        'ajax': {
                            'url': "{{ url_for('.table_b') }}",
                            'type': 'GET',
                            'data': {
                                'orderColumns': order_columns,
                            },
                        },
                        'columns': [
                            { 'title': 'Column Date', 'data': 'column_date' },
                            { 'title': 'Column B', 'data': 'column_b' },
                        ],
                        'columnDefs': [
                            {
                                'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
                                    return "<div class='text-wrap width-200'>" + data + "</div>";
                                },
                                'targets': '_all',
                            }
                        ],
                    });

                    // Apply the search
                    table.columns().every( function (index) {
                        $('#table-b thead tr:eq(1) th:eq(' + index + ') input').on('keydown', function (event) {
                            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                                table.column($(this).parent().index() + ':visible')
                                    .search(this.value)
                                    .draw();
                            }
                        });
                    });

                }
            });
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

/app.py

```py
# Import packages
from datetime import date
from io import BytesIO

from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, send_file
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, DateTime, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, sessionmaker

app = Flask(__name__)


# Create a SQLite database engine
engine = create_engine(
    url='sqlite:///test.db',
    echo=False,
)

# Create a session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Create a base class for declarative models
Base = declarative_base()


# Define "table_a" model
class table_a(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_a'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    column_date = Column(DateTime)
    column_a = Column(String)


# Define "table_b" model
class table_b(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_b'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    column_date = Column(DateTime)
    column_b = Column(String)


with app.app_context():
    Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

    # Add sample data to the "table_a" table
    session.add_all(
        [
            table_a(column_date=date(2023, 11, 10), column_a='1'),
            table_a(column_date=date(2023, 10, 31), column_a='1'),
            table_a(column_date=date(2023, 10, 31), column_a='2'),
        ],
    )

    # Add sample data to the "table_b" table
    session.add_all(
        [
            table_b(column_date=date(2023, 11, 1), column_b='1'),
            table_b(column_date=date(2023, 11, 11), column_b='1'),
        ],
    )

    session.commit()


def read_table(*, table_name):
    # Read a SQLite database engine
    engine = create_engine(
        url='sqlite:///test.db',
        echo=False,
    )

    # Create a session
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    # Create a base class for declarative models
    Base = declarative_base()

    # Define "table_a" model
    class table_a(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'table_a'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        column_date = Column(DateTime)
        column_a = Column(String)

    # Define "table_b" model
    class table_b(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'table_b'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        column_date = Column(DateTime)
        column_b = Column(String)

    if table_name == 'table_a':
        sql_query = session.query(table_a)

        # Filters
        filter_column_date = request.args.get(
            key='columns[0][search][value]',
            default='',
            type=str,
        )
        filter_column_a = request.args.get(
            key='columns[1][search][value]',
            default='',
            type=str,
        )

        # Other parameters
        order_columns = request.args.get(key='orderColumns', default='', type=bool)

        if filter_column_date != '':
            sql_query = sql_query.filter(
                table_a.column_date.ilike(
                    f'%{filter_column_date}%',
                ),
            )

        if filter_column_a != '':
            sql_query = sql_query.filter(
                table_a.column_a.ilike(
                    f'%{filter_column_a}%',
                ),
            )

        if order_columns is True:
            sql_query = sql_query.order_by(table_a.column_date.asc())

    if table_name == 'table_b':
        sql_query = session.query(table_b)

        # Filters
        filter_column_date = request.args.get(
            key='columns[0][search][value]',
            default='',
            type=str,
        )
        filter_column_b = request.args.get(
            key='columns[1][search][value]',
            default='',
            type=str,
        )

        # Other parameters
        order_columns = request.args.get(key='orderColumns', default='', type=bool)

        if filter_column_date != '':
            sql_query = sql_query.filter(
                table_b.column_date.ilike(
                    f'%{filter_column_date}%',
                ),
            )

        if filter_column_b != '':
            sql_query = sql_query.filter(
                table_b.column_b.ilike(
                    f'%{filter_column_b}%',
                ),
            )

        if order_columns is True:
            sql_query = sql_query.order_by(table_b.column_date.asc())

    return sql_query


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template(template_name_or_list='index.html')


@app.route(rule='/table-a', methods=['GET'])
def table_a():
    # Get the pagination parameters from the request
    start = request.args.get(key='start', default=0, type=int)
    length = request.args.get(key='length', default=10, type=int)

    sql_query = read_table(table_name='table_a')

    response = {
        'draw': request.args.get(key='draw', default=1, type=int),
        'recordsTotal': sql_query.count(),
        'recordsFiltered': sql_query.count(),
        'data': jsonable_encoder(sql_query.offset(start).limit(length).all()),
    }

    return jsonify(response)


@app.route(rule='/table-b', methods=['GET'])
def table_b():
    # Get the pagination parameters from the request
    start = request.args.get(key='start', default=0, type=int)
    length = request.args.get(key='length', default=10, type=int)

    sql_query = read_table(table_name='table_b')

    response = {
        'draw': request.args.get(key='draw', default=1, type=int),
        'recordsTotal': sql_query.count(),
        'recordsFiltered': sql_query.count(),
        'data': jsonable_encoder(sql_query.offset(start).limit(length).all()),
    }

    return jsonify(response)


@app.route(rule='/database-download', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def database_download():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        table = request.form.get('table-selector')

    sql_query = read_table(table_name=f'{table}')

    # Create a binary data memory file
    buffer = BytesIO()

    df = pd.read_sql(
        sql=sql_query.statement,
        con=create_engine(
            url='sqlite:///test.db',
            echo=False,
        ),
        index_col=None,
        coerce_float=True,
        params=None,
        parse_dates=None,
        chunksize=None,
    )

    # DataFrame to buffer
    df.to_csv(
        path_or_buf=buffer,
        sep=',',
        na_rep='',
        header=True,
        index=False,
        index_label=None,
        encoding='utf-8-sig',
    )

    # Change the stream position to the start of the stream
    buffer.seek(0)

    return send_file(
        path_or_file=buffer,
        download_name=f'{table}.csv',
        as_attachment=True,
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=5011, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: using Flask's `flask.session`, I stored the request arguments (column filters) in the current session and retrieved them as a `werkzeug.ImmutableMultiDict` object to download the .csv with the applied filters once the download is requested. The final code can be found below:

/templates/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flask Application</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css"/>

        <style>
            .text-wrap{
                white-space:normal;
            }
            .width-200{
                width:200px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Table Viewer</h1>

        <form id="selector" action="{{ url_for('.database_download') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            Select table:
            <select id="table-selector" name="table-selector">
                <!-- <option disabled selected value>Select a Dataset</option> -->
                <option value="table_a" selected>Table A</option>
                <option value="table_b">Table B</option>
            </select>

        </form>

        <br>

        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="order-columns" value="True" checked> Order columns by date</p>


        <p><input type="button" id="button-database-selector" value="Select Table" /></p>


        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div id="content-a" class="table table-striped table-hover" style="display:none; width:100%; table-layout:fixed; overflow-x:auto;">

            <table id="table-a">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>

        </div>


        <div id="content-b" class="table table-striped table-hover" style="display:none; width:100%; table-layout:fixed; overflow-x:auto;">

            <table id="table-b">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>


        </div>

        <div id="download" style="display:none">

            <p>Download table: <input type="submit" value="Download" form="selector"></button></p>

    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready( function() {

            $('input[id="button-database-selector"]').click( function() {


                if ($('input[id="order-columns"]').prop('checked')) {
                    var order_columns = 'True';
                } else {
                    var order_columns = '';
                }

                var database_selected = $('select[id="table-selector"]').val();

                // Display download button
                $('div[id="download"]').css('display', 'block');

                if (database_selected == 'table_a') {

                    // Hide all tables
                    $('div[id^="content-"]').hide();

                    // Display table
                    $('div[id="content-a"]').css('display', 'block');

                    // Setup - add a text input to each header cell
                    $('#table-a thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function () {
                        var title = $('#table-a thead tr:eq(0) th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
                        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
                    } );

                    var table = $('table[id="table-a"]').DataTable({
                        'pageLength': 50,
                        'ordering': false,
                        // 'scrollX': true,
                        // 'sScrollX': '100%',
                        'searching': true,
                        'dom': 'lrtip',
                        'orderCellsTop': true,
                        'serverSide': true,
                        'bDestroy': true,
                        'ajax': {
                            'url': "{{ url_for('.table_a') }}",
                            'type': 'GET',
                            'data': {
                                'orderColumns': order_columns,
                            },
                        },
                        'columns': [
                            { 'title': 'Column Date', 'data': 'column_date' },
                            { 'title': 'Column A', 'data': 'column_a' },
                        ],
                        'columnDefs': [
                            {
                                'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
                                    return "<div class='text-wrap width-200'>" + data + "</div>";
                                },
                                'defaultContent': '',
                                'targets': '_all',
                            }
                        ],
                    });

                    // Apply the search
                    table.columns().every( function (index) {
                        $('#table-a thead tr:eq(1) th:eq(' + index + ') input').on('keydown', function (event) {
                            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                                table.column($(this).parent().index() + ':visible')
                                    .search(this.value)
                                    .draw();
                            }
                        });
                    });

                } else if (database_selected === 'table_b') {

                    // Hide all tables
                    $('div[id^="content-"]').hide();

                    // Display table
                    $('div[id="content-b"]').css('display', 'block');

                    // Setup - add a text input to each header cell
                    $('#table-b thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function () {
                        var title = $('#table-b thead tr:eq(0) th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
                        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
                    } );

                    var table = $('table[id="table-b"]').DataTable({
                        'pageLength': 50,
                        'ordering': false,
                        // 'scrollX': true,
                        // 'sScrollX': '100%',
                        'searching': true,
                        'dom': 'lrtip',
                        'orderCellsTop': true,
                        'serverSide': true,
                        'bDestroy': true,
                        'ajax': {
                            'url': "{{ url_for('.table_b') }}",
                            'type': 'GET',
                            'data': {
                                'orderColumns': order_columns,
                            },
                        },
                        'columns': [
                            { 'title': 'Column Date', 'data': 'column_date' },
                            { 'title': 'Column B', 'data': 'column_b' },
                        ],
                        'columnDefs': [
                            {
                                'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
                                    return "<div class='text-wrap width-200'>" + data + "</div>";
                                },
                                'defaultContent': '',
                                'targets': '_all',
                            }
                        ],
                    });

                    // Apply the search
                    table.columns().every( function (index) {
                        $('#table-b thead tr:eq(1) th:eq(' + index + ') input').on('keydown', function (event) {
                            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                                table.column($(this).parent().index() + ':visible')
                                    .search(this.value)
                                    .draw();
                            }
                        });
                    });

                }
            });
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

/app.py

```py
# Import packages
from datetime import date
from io import BytesIO
import secrets

from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, send_file, session
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, DateTime, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, sessionmaker
from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableMultiDict

app = Flask(__name__)


# Create a SQLite database engine
engine = create_engine(
    url='sqlite:///test.db',
    echo=False,
)

# Create a session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session_db = Session()

# Create a base class for declarative models
Base = declarative_base()


# Define "table_a" model
class table_a(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_a'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    column_date = Column(DateTime)
    column_a = Column(String)


# Define "table_b" model
class table_b(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_b'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    column_date = Column(DateTime)
    column_b = Column(String)


with app.app_context():
    Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

    # Add sample data to the "table_a" table
    session_db.add_all(
        [
            table_a(column_date=date(2023, 11, 10), column_a='1'),
            table_a(column_date=date(2023, 10, 31), column_a='1'),
            table_a(column_date=date(2023, 10, 31), column_a='2'),
        ],
    )

    # Add sample data to the "table_b" table
    session_db.add_all(
        [
            table_b(column_date=date(2023, 11, 1), column_b='1'),
            table_b(column_date=date(2023, 11, 11), column_b='1'),
        ],
    )

    session_db.commit()


def read_table(*, table_name, request_dict):
    # Read a SQLite database engine
    engine = create_engine(
        url='sqlite:///test.db',
        echo=False,
    )

    # Create a session_db
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session_db = Session()

    # Create a base class for declarative models
    Base = declarative_base()

    # Define "table_a" model
    class table_a(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'table_a'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        column_date = Column(DateTime)
        column_a = Column(String)

    # Define "table_b" model
    class table_b(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'table_b'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        column_date = Column(DateTime)
        column_b = Column(String)

    if table_name == 'table_a':
        sql_query = session_db.query(table_a)

        # Filters
        filter_column_date = request_dict.get(
            key='columns[0][search][value]',
            default='',
            type=str,
        )
        filter_column_a = request_dict.get(
            key='columns[1][search][value]',
            default='',
            type=str,
        )

        # Other parameters
        order_columns = request_dict.get(key='orderColumns', default='', type=bool)

        if filter_column_date != '':
            sql_query = sql_query.filter(
                table_a.column_date.ilike(
                    f'%{filter_column_date}%',
                ),
            )

        if filter_column_a != '':
            sql_query = sql_query.filter(
                table_a.column_a.ilike(
                    f'%{filter_column_a}%',
                ),
            )

        if order_columns is True:
            sql_query = sql_query.order_by(table_a.column_date.asc())

    if table_name == 'table_b':
        sql_query = session_db.query(table_b)

        # Filters
        filter_column_date = request_dict.get(
            key='columns[0][search][value]',
            default='',
            type=str,
        )
        filter_column_b = request_dict.get(
            key='columns[1][search][value]',
            default='',
            type=str,
        )

        # Other parameters
        order_columns = request_dict.get(key='orderColumns', default='', type=bool)

        if filter_column_date != '':
            sql_query = sql_query.filter(
                table_b.column_date.ilike(
                    f'%{filter_column_date}%',
                ),
            )

        if filter_column_b != '':
            sql_query = sql_query.filter(
                table_b.column_b.ilike(
                    f'%{filter_column_b}%',
                ),
            )

        if order_columns is True:
            sql_query = sql_query.order_by(table_b.column_date.asc())

    return sql_query


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template(template_name_or_list='index.html')


@app.route(rule='/table-a', methods=['GET'])
def table_a():
    # Get request arguments from the request
    request_dict = request.args

    # Store request arguments in current session
    session['REQUEST_DICT'] = request_dict

    # Get the pagination arguments from the request
    start = request_dict.get(key='start', default=0, type=int)
    length = request_dict.get(key='length', default=10, type=int)

    sql_query = read_table(table_name='table_a', request_dict=request_dict)

    response = {
        'draw': request_dict.get(key='draw', default=1, type=int),
        'recordsTotal': sql_query.count(),
        'recordsFiltered': sql_query.count(),
        'data': jsonable_encoder(obj=sql_query.offset(start).limit(length).all(), exclude_none=False, sqlalchemy_safe=True),
    }

    return jsonify(response)


@app.route(rule='/table-b', methods=['GET'])
def table_b():
    # Get request arguments from the request
    request_dict = request.args

    # Store request arguments in current session
    session['REQUEST_DICT'] = request_dict

    # Get the pagination arguments from the request
    start = request_dict.get(key='start', default=0, type=int)
    length = request_dict.get(key='length', default=10, type=int)

    sql_query = read_table(table_name='table_b', request_dict=request_dict)

    response = {
        'draw': request_dict.get(key='draw', default=1, type=int),
        'recordsTotal': sql_query.count(),
        'recordsFiltered': sql_query.count(),
        'data': jsonable_encoder(obj=sql_query.offset(start).limit(length).all(), exclude_none=False, sqlalchemy_safe=True),
    }

    return jsonify(response)


@app.route(rule='/database-download', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def database_download():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        table = request.form.get('table-selector')

    request_dict = ImmutableMultiDict(session['REQUEST_DICT'])

    sql_query = read_table(table_name=f'{table}', request_dict=request_dict)

    # Create a binary data memory file
    buffer = BytesIO()

    df = pd.read_sql(
        sql=sql_query.statement,
        con=create_engine(
            url='sqlite:///test.db',
            echo=False,
        ),
        index_col=None,
        coerce_float=True,
        params=None,
        parse_dates=None,
        chunksize=None,
    )

    # DataFrame to buffer
    df.to_csv(
        path_or_buf=buffer,
        sep=',',
        na_rep='',
        header=True,
        index=False,
        index_label=None,
        encoding='utf-8-sig',
    )

    # Change the stream position to the start of the stream
    buffer.seek(0)

    return send_file(
        path_or_file=buffer,
        download_name=f'{table}.csv',
        as_attachment=True,
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = secrets.token_urlsafe(nbytes=16)
    app.run(host='localhost', port=5011, debug=True)
```